# Efficient data transfer from REST API server to Ray Pipeline

Tags: python, python-asyncio, ray

I have a ML pipeline with multiple Ray (https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) actors (1 Tensorflow, a few preprocessing steps and a few post processing) connected to each other.

I would now like to make this pipeline available via a REST API which should accept images, put the images into the pipeline (executed by Ray) and respond the results back.

I was wondering what the best and most efficient architectural decision is to make Ray's remote functions publicly available via a REST API?
The images can be quite large, so ideally the code block where the REST API is running should be able to put the image directly into Ray's Plasma Storage.

I'm running Ray in a kubernetes cluster.
The REST API sever is Python / asyncio based.

One easy solution is:

- Spawn a kubernetes pod serving a REST API server and use `ray.init(...)` inside this container to connect to the Ray cluster and transfer data into the pipeline.
  However, I think in this way, the REST API pod will not be able to push the image data directly into Ray's shared memory?
  In this image (https://youtu.be/D_oz7E4v-U0?t=830) I can see it is normal to have multiple workers/drivers on 1 physical machine. But does this also count if Ray is running inside Docker/Kubernetes? In the kubernetes deployment example, there is a setting to explicitly have only 1 worker per node (https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/kubernetes/worker.yaml#L18).

Another (hacky?) solution is:

- Implement the REST API server inside a Ray Worker pod. In this way I assume the REST API code will be able to access the same shared memory as the worker does, assuring efficient data transfer.

The last option is:

- Implement the API Server as a Ray function or Ray actor. But if the function/actor gets deployed on a random node inside the Ray cluster, I'm not sure how to publicly expose this API Server..

Can someone with more insight in Ray help me with the best option (one of the above or something else)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding option 1, to run `ray.init(...)` in a pod, the pod must be part of the Ray cluster. Then you can put stuff in the object store via `ray.put` or passing the argument into a remote function (you can do `ray start` inside of this pod also). Using a single object store for shared memory between pods on the same physical machine probably is possible, but I haven't tried it. For Solution 3, you can control placement with Ray's custom resources. E.g., start a Ray node with `ray start --resources='{"Server": 1}'` and declare the server actor with `@ray.remote(resources={"Server": 1})`.

Comment: It might also be worth taking a look at the beginning of a serving library that was implemented in https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/4095.

Comment: Thanks for your swift support!
So when running multiple pods on a single physical machine, each pod will have its own object store, as if they were on separate machines. But data transfer between these object stores on a single machine will probably be quite efficient?

Comment: Right, if you run `ray start` in each pod (which is probaby the easiest thing to do), then each pod will have its own object store. Data transfer would probably be pretty quick, but it's worth testing. I'd expect performance to be best when using a single Ray pod per physical machine.